# MongoDB multidimensional array projection

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, aggregation-framework

I just started learning MongoDB and can't find a solution for my problem.

Got that document:

```
> db.test.insert({"name" : "Anika", "arr" : [ [11, 22],[33,44] ] })
```

Please note the "arr" field which is a multidimensional array.

Now I'm looking for a query that returns only the value of arr[0][1] which is 22. I tried to achieve that by using $slice, however I don't know how to address the second dimension with that.

```
> db.test.find({},{_id:0,"arr":{$slice: [0,1]}})
{ "name" : "ha", "arr" : [ [ 11, 22 ] ] }
```

I also tried

```
> db.test.find({},{_id:0,"arr":{$slice: [0,1][1,1]}})
{ "name" : "ha", "arr" : [ [ 11, 22 ] ] }
```

The desired output would be either

```
22
```

or

```
{"arr":[[22]]}
```

Thank you

---

**EDIT:**

After reading the comments I think that I've simplified the example data too much and I have to provide more information:

1. There are many more documents in the collection like that one that
   I've provided. But they all have the same structure.
2. There are more array elements than just two
3. In the real world the array contains really long texts (500kb-1mb),
   so it is very expansive to transmit the whole data to the client.
4. Before the aggregation I will do a query by the 'name' field. Just
   skipped that in the example for the sake of simplicity.
5. The target indexes are variable, so sometimes I need to know the
   value of arr[0][1], the next time it is arr[1][4]

---

example data:

```
> db.test.insert({"name" : "Olivia", "arr" : [ [11, 22, 33, 44],[55,66,77,88],[99] ] })
> db.test.insert({"name" : "Walter", "arr" : [ [11], [22, 33, 44],[55,66,77,88],[99] ] })
> db.test.insert({"name" : "Astrid", "arr" : [ [11, 22, 33, 44],[55,66],[77,88],[99] ] })
> db.test.insert({"name" : "Peter",  "arr" : [ [11, 22, 33, 44],[55,66,77,88],[99] ] })
```

example query:

```
> db.test.find({name:"Olivia"},{"arr:"...})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$arr' },
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $project: { _id: 0, arr: 1 } },
    { $unwind: '$arr' },
    { $skip: 1 },
    { $limit: 1 }
])
```

Returns:

```
{ "arr": 22 }
```

**Edit:** The original poster has modified my solution to suit his needs and came up with the following:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: { name:"Olivia" } },
    { $project: { _id: 0,arr: 1 } },
    { $unwind: '$arr' },
    { $skip: 1 },
    { $limit:1 },
    { $unwind: "$arr" },
    { $skip: 2 },
    { $limit: 1 }
])
```

This query will result in `{ arr: 77 }` given the extended data provided by the OP. Note that $skip and $limit are needed to select the right elements in the array hierarchy.

Comment: This cannot work on anything other than a single document. Sure `$skip` and `$limit` "simulate" indexed positions, but once you `$unwind` on multiple collection documents this becomes irrelevant.

Comment: It will work if the desired output **is** for a single document. It's always possible to get only one desired document by using `$match`.

Comment: It never realisticallly will be. This is about giving people "real" examples that they can really use. Single document cases are better coded in the client as I stated in my answer.

Comment: The question says: *"The desired output would be either `22` ..."*. I am pretty sure they only need one document's value *as a result*.

Comment: *"Real world"*. Read above. You don't teach people with edge case or unrealistic examples. I'm all about *"teaching people"*. So that's why you upvote, and not just just for a *"it happens to works"* ( bad english intended ) attempt at an answer. Do you really think this helps? Or did you upvote ( your words ) somethign informative that does actually help?

Comment: That is almost what I'm looking for. Based on your code I was able to find the solution that addresses my problem entirely:`> db.test.aggregate([{$match: {name:"Olivia"}}, {$project: {_id:0,arr:1}},{ $unwind: '$arr' },{$skip: 1},{$limit:1},{$unwind:"$arr"},{$skip:2},{$limit:1}])`. Could you update your answer, so I can mark it as the correct one?

Comment: Anyhow I'm surprised that such a simple task requires so much code. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Humppakäräjät Done. I am glad I could help!

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko you forgot to add a line break at `{ $unwind: '$arr' }, { $skip: 1 },` and could you please add a description that points out that the two `$skip`s are the way to select the fields? (arr[i][n]) That would help people with less experience of MongoDB (like me) to understand that code much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

The `$slice` form you ask for does not do multi-dimentional arrays. Each array is considered individually, and is therefore not supported that way by the current `$slice`.

As such it is actually done a lot shorter on indexed "first" and "last" values than has been suggested using `.aggregate()`, and presently:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$arr" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "arr": { "$first": "$arr" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$arr" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "arr": { "$last": "$arr" }
    }}
])
```

But in future releases of MongoDB ( currently works in development branch 3.18 as of writing ) you have `$arrayElemAt` as an operator for the aggregation framework which works like this:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "arr": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
                { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$arr", 0 ] },
                1
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Both basically come to the same `{ "arr": 22 }` result, though the future available form works quite flexibly on array index values, rather than first and last.

Comment: It's good to know about `$arrayElemAt `! Thanks for sharing. I have a question about your use of aggregation operators though. Isn't `$group` more expensive compared to `$limit` in my example?

Comment: Also, if you don't know the number of elements in an array, you probably wouldn't be able to use `$first` and `$last`. So the use of `$limit` looks more versatile to me.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Nope. The more aggregatation pipeline stages == the more expensive. FULL STOP. Less is better. Of course the new operators ( when they become available ) means a single stage, which is therefore the best result. In all honesty, if this is the full complexity of what you are asking then the aggregation framework is not "presently" the answer. Do it in client code instead, which is much more efficient.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Oh yeah. And without a `$group` operation then then other presented "answer" ( ironic bunny ears intended ) cannot possibly work on an unwound array.

Comment: The other presented "answer" is written by me. Could you please explain why it cannot work without grouping? I tested it and it did work.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Geez Really ( not person asking question) then perhaps you might realize that without a `$group` then any `$skip` or `$limit` operation works "across documents and not a single one". So big fail. Just because someone asks a question with a single document does not make your simplified solution correct. So that is why you are completely incorrect. Only have not downvoted you because I was giving you the opportunity to realize how incorrect you are.

Comment: I am assuming that they only want to receive information about *one* document, which they can do by using `$match`. This assumption comes from the fact that one of the formats of the desired output provided in the question is simply `22`.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, by the way. Although I don't think it will necessarily work correctly for the original poster. For example, given the following array: `"arr" : [ [11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66], [77, 88, 99] ]`, how do you select the element at `[1][1]`?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Nobody ever does this with one document. So pretty silly to argue.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I'm afraid my question wasn't detailed enough. As @DmytroShevchenko correctly assumed the arrays can have  more than just two fields. It is surely possible that I need to select `arr[1][1]` from : `"arr" : [ [11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66], [77, 88, 99] ]`. So `$last` and `$first` won't help me much.

Comment: @Humppakäräjät Such a shame you and your accepted answerer got this so completely wrong. That answer is the antithesis of a correct process for handling the problem, and completely incorrect. If you want a single document ( the only case that works for ) then using standard array index notation ( in client code ) is the most optimal way to go.. I am showing the broader case of working with multiple documents, and also stated that client code is the best way for single documents in the anwser. So you did it wrong and accepted the wrong advice.