# Finding specific object(s) from multiple arrays and then do crud operations with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is a screenshot of my collection:

[image]

Here is my query:

```
db.collection("collection_name").aggregate(
[
{$match: 
{br_date: this.data.date}
}
]).toArray()
```

And, this is what I get

```
_id: id,
brdate: 10-08-2022
brName: "Principal Branch, Dhaka",
email: "example_email,
loans: [

[
{loan_id: 1, loan_name: X, category: "rural"},
{loan_id: 2, loan_name: Y, category: "urban"},
{loan_id: 3, loan_name: Z, category: "rural"}
],

[
{loan_id: 4, loan_name: A, category: "rural"},
{loan_id: 5, loan_name: B, category: "urban"}
],

]
```

**Question 1:**
I would like to show the loans depending on their category. Let's say, I would like to show the loans that are from "rural" category. How do I do that?

**Question 2:**
I may have to delete a loan that matches the loan_id. How do I do that?

**Question 3:** I may have to update a loan that matches the loan_id. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `loans` is an array of arrays I would use `$[<i>]` filtered positional operator:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

1.

```js
db.testie.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        _id: { $eq: ObjectId("62fb3af6a9b543178fb28bb5"), }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: '$loans'
}, {
    $unwind: '$loans'
}, {
    $group: { _id: "$loans.category", loanCategory: { $addToSet: '$loans' } }
}])
```

2. 

```js
db.collection.updateOne({
    "_id" : id,
}, {
    $pull: { 'loans.$[]': { 'category': 'test_category' } }
});
```

3. 

```js
db.collection.updateOne({
    "_id" : id,
}, {
    $set: { 'loans.$[].$[loan].category': 'test_category' }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [{ 'loan.loan_id': 3 }]
});
```

Aggregation:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/8NmT6Qn3Wh7

Delete
https://mongoplayground.net/p/LUDrpDLP6kN

Update
https://mongoplayground.net/p/sRAvJiWOYmV

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working. I'm adding a screenshot of my collection. Could you please look at it and suggest how I should proceed ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly is not working? In order to update a specific element in array you should use positional operator: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: In my question, there is Array. Inside that Array there is another array or couple of arrays. And, inside those arrays, there are objects. So, you can see, there is slight difference. Your code would work if I had an Array, inside that array there are objects. For the aggregation task, this one helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034524/mongodb-multidimensional-array-projection

Because I had arrays inside arrays, I needed double unwind there.

Comment: @Rashel okay now I understand your usecase. I have updated my post, take a look.

Comment: I'm sorry I was away from computer for two days. Btw, the updated answer works perfectly. Thanks. I've created mongodb playground shared code and added the codes to your answer.